# Why setTimeout() with 0 ms. is affect in my function

Tags: jquery, settimeout

In my case when hovering `<div>` so prepend one element inside the `<div>`

But in some div i want to hide prepended element after hovered element.

This is my code and its work !

**HTML :**

```
<div class="one">
    <span class="content"></span>
</div>


<div class="two">
    <span class="content"></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("div.one > .content").on("hover" , function(){
    var this_ = $(this);
    this_.prev(".top").remove();
});


$("div.two > .content").on("hover" ,function(){
    var this_ = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){this_.prev(".top").remove();})
});
```

`.one` and `.two` both are same function, But I want to know why second function affect when I using `setTimeout()` and timing is 0 millisecond , **Why 0 millisecond is affect in my function ?**

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/nShCy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 0 ms, it's [4 ms delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting).

The answer is simple: mouseenter is fired after hover, so you're trying to remove the element that doesn't exist yet. With a 4ms pause and a hover callback that finishes in less than 4 ms it works as expected.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function(){

            $("div.one > .content").on("hover" , function(){
            var this_ = $(this);
            this_.prev(".top").remove();
        });


        $("div.two > .content").on("hover" ,function(){
            var this_ = $(this);
            setTimeout(function(){this_.prev(".top").remove();})
        });

})
```

Comment: Admittedly the question is a bit hard to understand, but this doesn't answer it at all. (Note that the jsfiddle script is already loading on dom ready.)